# SUM 2 columns with 2 columns same name

Tags: mysql, php

I have this table `id, teama, teamb, pointa, pointb`.

Columns `teama` and `teamb` containing the same names. I want to output the sum grouped by `teama` from `teama` where `pointa` and where `teamb pointb`.

for example:

```
id, teama, teamb, pointa, pointb
1,  aa,    bb,    1,      2
2,  bb,    aa,    2,      1
```

What  want as result:

```
aa, 2
bb, 4
```

I'm really stuck on this one. I'm using MySQL and PHP.

Comment: I don't understand how you get from your sample data to your sample output.

Comment: @Erik Me neither. What sport is this and what is the points scheme for winning and losing?

Comment: Perhaps if you explain the use case driving this query/requirement it would be easier to figure out....

Comment: Its volleybal and there are 3 sets played. output goes thru teama point won and lost and total games played

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a list of match results and you want to get won/lost points:

```
SELECT team, SUM(pointa), SUM(pointb)
FROM
 ( -- use all rows twice with switched points
   SELECT teama AS team, pointa, pointb
   FROM tab
   UNION ALL
   SELECT teamb, pointb, pointa
   FROM tab
 ) AS dt
GROUP BY team
```

Comment: That would mimic the provided sample output but I can't imagine this would give the desired output when there are more team names. Then again I don't have a clue what the OP is actually looking for so this might be spot on....

Comment: the code from dnoeth doesnt work for me..... the output should be like this<br>

Comment: teama, point won, point los point los i calculate becouse there are only 3 sets played.

Comment: @Andre the output of this query should match the output you specified on your question (it actually provides one extra column, just remove `, SUM(pointb)` and the output should match exactly). If you want something else, please update your question's desired output.